# How to convert a remote webp image to a png image to load it into node-canvas

Tags: node.js, canvas, webp, node-canvas

Usually I import png images into Canvas by using

```
const image = Canvas.LoadImage('url.png')
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(256,256)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.drawImage(image,256,256)
```

but when i try to import a webp image, I get an error saying that webp isn't supported. On research into the Issues of node-canvas I found [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1258), The importing issue appears to be solved but I dont understand how to import the webp images now.

I tried using the Image, ImageFromBuffer(await fetch(url).buffer()) from the [fix in the issue](http://%20https://github.com/node-gfx/image) but both give errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by using the library [Sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/).

First get the file as a buffer

```js
// axios for remote images- maybe fs for local images?
const imageResponse = await axios.get(url, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      });
```

Convert the file to png using sharp:

```
const img = await sharp(imageResponse.data).toFormat('png').toBuffer();
```

Then you can use loadImage

```
const file = await loadImage(img).then((image) => {
      ctx.drawImage(
        image,
        256,
        256
      );

      return { buffer: canvas.toBuffer(), mimetype: `image/png` };
    });
```